# SQL query to list department names in descending order of employee count

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write an SQL query to list department names in descending order of employee count ?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY to count, use ORDER BY to sort.

Comment: jarlh's comment is just right for a general question. If you give a table design and the query which you wrote that didn't work, then someone can give a more specific answer. Being specific and showing a trial is encouraged at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT     Department.DeptName, COUNT(Employee.FName) AS EmpCount
FROM         Employee INNER JOIN
                      Department ON Employee.DeptId = Department.ID
GROUP BY Department.DeptName
order by EmpCount
```

Comment: I'd do Departments LEFT JOIN Employees to also include departments without any employees in the result.

Comment: I finally ended up writing the same query :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is different tables, you can put correlated subquery in `ORDER BY` section. Or you can join tables, then group them and then `order by count DESC`.

Second is better for performance